# SAPI Execution Priority

Tags: vb.net, performance, sapi

I use (SAPI) object in my application. However, whenever I executes its function, the voice runs but the application's performance (everything else) gets paused until the voice finishes! I wonder if that has something to do with the priority of this Speaking-Object. Can I somehow lower it until the rest of the code executes first? o_O

```
Private Function Lara(ByVal script As String) As Object
    Lara = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
    Lara.Voice = Lara.GetVoices.Item(1)
    Return Lara.speak(script)
End Function

Private Sub Test_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Logo.Visible = True
    Logo.Image = ResizeImage(My.Resources.Spell)
    Lara("Welcome")
End Sub
```

Can (Lara) say "welcome" AFTER loading the form and its Logo?

Thank you.

---

Thanks to Ms. Lesley Gushurst, the voice now runs according the code order (Application shows up, its logo, then the voice). The solution was to add a (com-reference) to the project named "Microsoft Speech Object Library", then importing it in the code.

```
Imports SpeechLib

Private Sub Test_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Logo.Visible = True
        Logo.Image = My.Resources.Spell
        Dim Lara = CreateObject("SAPI.spvoice")
        Lara.Voice = Lara.GetVoices.Item(1)
        Lara.speak("Welcome", SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync) 'It's declared now!
End Sub
```

Comment: See the [**Form.Shown event**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.shown(v=vs.110).aspx), however you might want to run this in another thread if it's a blocking call.

Comment: Thanks, Mr. Vincent. But my question is about lowering SAPI's priority in general. Thus, SHOWN event-handler will not accomplish that.

Comment: There is no such thing as "priority" when it comes to code execution. It is either synchronous, asynchronous or multithreaded synchronous/asynchronous.

Comment: Roger that, Mr. Vincent. ^_^

Comment: Good :)! If the code is executed synchronously, execution will stay on the same line of code until that line has finished executing. `Lara.speak()` is a synchronous call which also seems to block until it's finished talking, which is why it blocks the rest from executing.

Comment: I see... Well, live and learn, right! 'Much obliged, Mr. Vincent. ^_^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you take a look at MSDN's documentation [SpVoice Speak method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms723609%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), it states that

> "When synchronous speech is used in an application, the application's
>   execution is blocked while the voice speaks, and the user is
>   effectively locked out. This may be acceptable for simple
>   applications, or those with no graphical user interface (GUI), but
>   when sophisticated user interaction is intended, asynchronous speaking
>   will generally be more appropriate."

So what you'll probably want to do is look into calling speak with the SVSFlagsAsync being set. As it is right now your execution is being blocked.

I'm thinking your code would look like:

```
Lara.speak(script, SpeechVoiceSpeakFlags.SVSFlagsAsync)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Yet, when I use it inside my function's return, then it tells me that (SpeechVoiceSpeaFlags) is not declared. How may I declare that Enum exactly; before even calling it?

Comment: This website seems to have a working example of what you're looking to do http://vbcity.com/forums/t/166589.aspx ... I don't normally work with VB, but if you're still having problems I can look into it further.

Comment: Wowser! It worked. It was all about adding "Microsoft Speech Object Library" to the project's references, then "imports" it before the main class. Thank you kindly, Ms. Lesley. ^_^

Answer (score 0):

I wish mine was that easy.  Mine SWITCHES voices on the fly according to the voices embedded in the text to be read.  And I am fast finding out that not too many people are trying to do that.

My apps is a Visual Basic (VS2010) verbal editing tool for writers that speaks the chapter or story so the author can HEAR typos, incoherent sentences, etc. in male or female voices, depending on which character is speaking.  Right now I have only 7 voices that are available although at one time I have had 12 and with 22 different characters assigned to them.

It worked fine on windows 7, 8 and 8.1 but started having big problems windows text.

When I finally get it working I will make the code available, maybe.